# Hibernate Criterion IN Clause 1000 break up

Tags: java, hibernate, database-performance

Hi i have this large oracle hibernate web applications and it seems to give this error

`ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000`

and i need a java code tested by someone as a hibernate user defined component to add to my search java classes in my screen as easy as possible could someone have such tested component?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I tried this below code from [link](http://mpujari.blogspot.com/2010/11/hibernate-criterion-in-clause-1000.html) and it seem to work beautifully i will paste the code in-case the link were broken in future.

Keep it Simple Keep it Smile :)

```
/**
 * An utility method to build the Criterion Query IN clause if the number of parameter
 * values passed has a size more than 1000. Oracle does not allow more than
 * 1000 parameter values in a IN clause. Doing so a {@link SQLException} is
 * thrown with error code, 'ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000'.
 * @param propertyName
 * @param values
 * @return
 */
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

/**
 *
 * @author 2796
 */
public class SplitHibernateIn {

    private static int PARAMETER_LIMIT = 999;

    public static org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion buildInCriterion(String propertyName, List values) {
        org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion criterion = null;

        int listSize = values.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i += PARAMETER_LIMIT) {
            List subList;
            if (listSize > i + PARAMETER_LIMIT) {
                subList = values.subList(i, (i + PARAMETER_LIMIT));
            } else {
                subList = values.subList(i, listSize);
            }
            if (criterion != null) {
                criterion = Restrictions.or(criterion, Restrictions.in(propertyName, subList));
            } else {
                criterion = Restrictions.in(propertyName, subList);
            }
        }
        return criterion;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI ; This code were tested on hibernate 3 and oracle 10g

Comment: If someone (like me) thinks that IN clause should return nothing for no arguments (for empty list passed as an argument), one can modify this method returning a Criterion which is always false.
I did it by adding a following code at the top of the method:
if ((values == null) || values.isEmpty()) { return Restrictions.sqlRestriction("(1=0)"); }

Answer (score 4):

The same idea, but using javax Predicate.

```
private static int PARAMETER_LIMIT = 999;

private static Predicate createInStatement(CriteriaBuilder cb, Path fieldName, List values) {
    int listSize = values.size();
    Predicate predicate = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i += PARAMETER_LIMIT) {
        List subList;
        if (listSize > i + PARAMETER_LIMIT) {
            subList = values.subList(i, (i + PARAMETER_LIMIT));
        } else {
            subList = values.subList(i, listSize);
        }
        if (predicate == null) {
            predicate = fieldName.in(subList);
        } else {
            predicate = cb.or(predicate, fieldName.in(subList));
        }
    }
    return predicate;
}
```

And the usage

```
public List<Bean> getBeanList(List<Long> pkList) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Bean> query = cb.createQuery(Bean.class);
    Root<Bean> root = query.from(Bean.class);

    // "Bean_" is a @StaticMetamodel(Bean.class)
    Predicate inStatement = createInStatement(cb, root.get(Bean_.pk), pkList);

    query.select(root).where(inStatement);
    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: This does not work for MS SQL where the limit is 2100 parameters! It seems the JDBC Driver concatenates the OR-ed IN clauses?!

Answer (score 1):

While current answers are fine, I think this one is simpler both to implement and to understand:

```
private <T> Disjunction restrictionPropertyIn(String property, ArrayList<T> list) {
    Disjunction criterion = Restrictions.disjunction();
    for (List<T> idSubset : Lists.partition(list, 1000)) {
        criterion.add(Restrictions.in(property, idSubset));
    }
    return criterion;
}
```

- `Restrictions.disjunction()` is equivalent to concatenating several `Criteria` using `Restrictions.or()`.
- `Lists` is a utility class from Guava; `partition(list, limit)` splits `list` into sublists of size `limit`.

The returned `Criterion` can be used as-is in any place a `Criterion` is expected, like:

```
List<Long> fiveThousandIds = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, ..., 999, 1000, 1001, ..., 5000);
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
crit.add(restrictionPropertyIn("employeeId", fiveThousandIds));
crit.list();
```

If you need to support different DBs with different `IN` clause limits, you can turn the hardcoded `1000` into a parameter instead.

Comment: Didn't they say that the performance of `OR`ing these parts is poor?

Comment: @geneb. Did they? Please provide a source, because I would expect the Oracle SQL "compiler" to have this oh-so-common use of `X IN (...) OR X IN (...)` accounted for and optimized since version 8 at least. Besides, every answer to this question uses `OR`; mine just does so in 4 lines instead of 20. This is the way we've been doing it for several years now.