# Hibernate Native Query in Criteria predicate

Tags: hibernate, jpql

I am trying to find a solution for the IN clause restriction in Oracle DB

As part of predicates , there may be IN clauses which has too many values.
I would like to replace those IN clauses with a native sql

As per the below link  , it may be possible to have native sql embedded as part of criteria predicate

[Using native sql in java criteria predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667680/using-native-sql-in-java-criteria-predicate)

Below is my scenario. I am trying to replace the IN condition in the predicate with the native SQL

**SELECT * FROM TABLE (SELECT CAST(? AS NUMBERTABLE) FROM DUAL)**

```
(OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement( 
"SELECT ENAME FROM EMP " + 
"WHERE EMPNO IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE (SELECT CAST(? AS NUMBERTABLE) FROM DUAL))"); 
pstat.setARRAY(1, array_to_pass); 
OracleResultSet rset = (OracleResultSet) pstat.executeQuery();
```

Is this feasible using criteriaBuilder function method ?

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869054/hibernate-criterion-in-clause-1000-break-up 
Maybe will help you.